# Project priority for VM availability

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there some kind of seniority/priority in Google Cloud for VM availability?

I currently have two different projects, each of which has a VM in the us-west-1-b region. I am trying to start an `n1-standard-16` instance with 1 T4 GPU in each project. In one of the projects, I am able to do so and start working immediately. In the other project, I get an error indicating that there are no machines with the requested configuration available in the region. How is this possible?

The only major difference between the projects is one is within my organization (a university), and the other is not. I am having trouble starting a VM in the project that is within my organization. I don't think this is a matter of getting lucky with one project and not the other, because I systematically have difficulty accessing machines in the institutional project, and have never had that kind of problem in the other project.

Comment: Is there an error message when you deploy the VM? that would be a good lead on how to solve the issue.